# How to change quarkus-vertx eventBus ClusterManager options

Tags: vert.x, quarkus, vertx-eventbus

I want to configure vertx at k8s by using hazelcast-kubernetes in Quarkus.

I need configure event-bus like this:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
            config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true)
                    .setProperty("namespace", "services")
                    .setProperty("service-name", "hazelcast-services");

ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager(config);
VertxOptions options= new VertxOptions();
options.setClusterManager(mgr);
```

How to pass custom configured VertxOptions to Quarkus-vertx?

I found in [VertxCoreRecorder](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/vertx-core/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/vertx/core/runtime/VertxCoreRecorder.java) class there is `List<Consumer<VertxOptions>>` parameter but i dont know how to create and pass own `Consumer<VertxOptions>` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can configure `VertxOptions` from code.

You could put a `cluster.xml` Hazelcast configuration file in the classpath instead.

Note that the Vert.x cluster managers are not supported in Quarkus yet. You can make them work in JVM mode (see this [attempt](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10889) with Infinispan) but not in native mode.